# typo3 APCu error

Tags: typo3, apcu

in my typo3 project we use a company internal web space. Currently an error message appears as shown in the picture.

[image]

On this APCu cannot be installed in the PHP configuration due to internal defaults.

How can I modify my typo3 instance so that I can do without APCu?

Comment: In the installtool you find the required option, it might depend on your TYPO3 version where it's located.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Install Tool and checkout the Configuration Presets. "Extbase object cache" is one of them. Change it to the database option.

Comment: This makes sense, but not for my problem at first. This seems to be the second step, because I can't open the backend without my solution.

Comment: @mapof: The Install Tool is accessible without Backend! (as it has always been). example.com/typo3/install

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution by myself.

In LocalConfiguration.php I searched for APCu and changed 'extbase_object' to the following:

```
 'SYS' => [
    'caching' => [
        'cacheConfigurations' => [
            'extbase_object' => [
                'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\NullBackend',
                'frontend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Frontend\\VariableFrontend',
                'groups' => [
                    'system',
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'defaultLifetime' => 0,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: `NullBackend` disables caching and has a negative impact on performance. You can use a `DatabaseBackend` or `SimpleFileBackend` as alternative. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/FrontendsBackends/Index.html#cache-backends for details...

Comment: Better use Install Tool to see all options described above then change it in LocalConfiguration.php

Comment: Thank you guys. Please read my answer at the comment from @M Klein